# find objects close to mine

Tags: iphone, dictionary, annotations

i am building an iphone app and i am looking for an idea how to get objects close to my position. the objects have an address listed in my database. now i am interested to show the objects that are close to mine on the map. how do i get that property? at first i thought of [floyd-warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall_algorithm) but is there an better solution than coding that myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to do is get Lat Long positions in your database instead of Addresses. There is a tool that google provides that does this. There is also a [manual approach](http://www.satsig.net/maps/lat-long-finder.htm).

Then you can use the [Haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula to work out if it is within a certain radius of your location.

Here is a example. You can cycle through your objects('s location) on the map and see how far away they are from you.

```
-(CGFloat) getDistance :(CGFloat)objLatitude :(CGFloat)objLongitude :(CGFloat)currentLocationLatitude :(CGFloat)currentLocationLongitude
{
    CGFloat earthRadius = 6371;

    CGFloat deltaLat = deg2rad(currentLocationLatitude - objLatitude);
    CGFloat deltaLong = deg2rad(objLongitude - currentLocationLongitude);

    CGFloat a = sin(deltaLat/2) * sin(deltaLat/2) +
        cos(deg2rad(objLatitude)) * cos(deg2rad((double)currentLocationLatitude)) * 
        sin(deltaLong/2) * sin(deltaLong/2);

    CGFloat c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));
    CGFloat d = earthRadius * c;

    d = round(d, 4); // round to 4dp
    d = d * 1000; // convert from km to m
    d = d * 0.621371192; // convert from km to miles

    return d; // m
}
```

You could amend this method to return TRUE if it is within a specific distance and FALSE if it does not:

```
-(BOOL) doesObjFallWithinMyRadius :(CGFloat)objLatitude :(CGFloat)objLongitude :(CGFloat)currentLocationLatitude :(CGFloat)currentLocationLongitude :(CGFloat)distanceLimit
{
    CGFloat earthRadius = 6371;

    CGFloat deltaLat = deg2rad(currentLocationLatitude - objLatitude);
    CGFloat deltaLong = deg2rad(objLongitude - currentLocationLongitude);

    CGFloat a = sin(deltaLat/2) * sin(deltaLat/2) +
        cos(deg2rad(objLatitude)) * cos(deg2rad((double)currentLocationLatitude)) * 
        sin(deltaLong/2) * sin(deltaLong/2);

    CGFloat c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));
    CGFloat d = earthRadius * c;

    d = round(d, 4); // round to 4dp
    d = d * 1000; // convert from km to m
    d = d * 0.621371192; // convert from km to miles

    if(d < distanceLimit) return TRUE;
    else return FALSE;
}
```

To find out your current location you will need to use the [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) which is part of the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the solution you want but this will help you to get distance between the locations. If you are plotting them on a Map u might have the coordinates. Then u can get the distance from these points to your location using `distanceFromlocation:` method of [CLLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) to get the distance. Then you can plot them based on the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen a [KD-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree)?  You can use this to find places near to you.

Of course, you'd have to assume that the Earth was flat, but I can't believe that can cause a problem right? :)  It's an interesting data structure to look at though.

Comment: Assuming the Earth is flat can give you skewed data over a long distance. Of course my answer above is not 100% correct because the earth is NOT perfectly round as the Haversine formula assumes.